# Expression engine Pro variable throws UNDEFINED VARIABLE: HEADER_SORTS after upgarde to EE7

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have upgrade Expression Engine from 5.3 to 7 after upgrade i am facing Notice like **UNDEFINED VARIABLE: HEADER_SORTS ee/ExpressionEngine/View/_shared/table.php, line 320**

Above error is faced in Pro Variables. Pro variable is coming from the name Low variables in old version of Expression engine(EE). In new version of Expression Engine the Low variables is the part of Expression engine a core system which remove the dependancy of third party package Low variables as in old version of EE.

If we are going to change in core file by defining constant than it's working fine, but it's not a proper solution as core file will be change any time while we are upgrading the version.

Comment: This is not about programming.  Have you contacted their support ?

Comment: @RohitGupta you are right i just connect their support community and issue found in the core file of the Expression Engine as i mentioned in my question. They will update the solution in next version of Expression Engine 7.2.6. Here is the reference url [Git Answer](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/2700)

Comment: Feel free to upvote my comment

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off asking this here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/
or in the EE Slack: https://eecms.slack.com/

Answer (score 0):

The issue found in the core file of expression engine file path ==> **UNDEFINED VARIABLE: HEADER_SORTS ee/ExpressionEngine/View/_shared/table.php, line 320**

You will get the fixed issue in next update of expression engine 7.2.6.

Reference Url: [Git Url](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/2700)